# Working MPMediaPickerController functions Started to give error but Why?

Tags: swift

I was using followings to pick audio in my app but started to get error and I can not now. Is there anyone have the same issues.

To set picker I was using

```
func selectAudioFromIpod() {
   
    let picker = MPMediaPickerController.init(mediaTypes:MPMediaType.anyAudio)
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

and get the media with this

```
func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController,
                 didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {
    
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: { [self] in
   
        let selectedAudio : NSArray = (mediaItemCollection.items as NSArray?)!
        let audioItem    = selectedAudio.object(at: 0)

        audioURL_iPOD = (audioItem as AnyObject).value(forProperty:  MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? URL
        
        
        if audioURL_iPOD != nil {
            
          
            audioAsset = AVAsset(url: audioURL_iPOD!) as AVAsset
            
            
        } else { // we could not pick audio from media library so we are
            
           print("Could not pick")
            
        }
       
    })
     
}
```

In Info.plist

Music Usage description and Media library usage description is set.

These are the error logs;

Entitlement: com.apple.accounts.appleaccount.fullaccess - Entitled: NO - Error: (null)

App[863:177114] [core] Attempted to register account monitor for types client is not authorized to access: {(
"com.apple.account.iTunesStore"
)}

[Default] <ICUserIdentityStoreACAccountBackend: 0x282ec9360> Failed to register for account monitoring. err=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "(null)"

[core] Attempted to register account monitor for types client is not authorized to access: {(
"com.apple.account.iTunesStore"

App[863:177114] [Default] ACAccountStore 0x283ff06c0 - Error retrieving iTunesStore accounts. err=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)"

App[863:177114] [Default] ACAccountStore 0x283ff06c0 - Error retrieving local store account. err=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)"

App[863:177114] [Default] [ICUserIdentityStore] Failed to fetch local store account with error: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)".

Comment: OK looks like if music files are not local this function does not work but I could not find how to get audio files from iCould either. I did  **picker.showsCloudItems = false** and solved it as temp. Because it does not show files on iCloud no error.

Comment: I did not work for me , I got similar error –

Answer (score 0):

Because music files erased from the device I was testing the application on and they are on iCloud, MPMediaPickerController was unable to pick the selected music. After downloading them to local storage the problem has been solved partially.

I used **picker.showsCloudItems = false** to prevent the files which are at iCloud to be seen by user to be picked .

Now, We should search how media on iCloud could be used by MPMediaPickerController.

Comment: Same problem for me:

Comment: I did not work for me , I got similar error

Comment: I am getting the same error. it says

Entitlement: com.apple.accounts.appleaccount.fullaccess - Entitled: NO - Error: (null)

Any idea how to solve this? what entitlements do I need to enable? I am using Xcode 14.2 (this problem existed in earlier versions as well but wasn't a priority until now)

Thank you